# Dense Stein subset in complex manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, stein-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth proper algebraic variety. Then $X$ has a dense affine open subset. In particular, any smooth proper algebraic variety has a dense Stein open subset as the complement of a divisor.

Does the same thing hold for compact complex manifolds? i.e.,

(1) Does any compact complex manifold have a dense Stein open subset?

(2) If (1) is true, can one take a dense Stein open subset as the complement of a divisor?

Comment: There are many compact complex manifolds which do not contain any divisors, e.g., a general complex torus of dimension at least two.

Comment: @ulrich's remark is absolutely correct but does not address the question, because the complement of an open Stein subset of a compact complex manifold has no reason to be a divisor nor even to be analytic.For example the complement  $U=\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\setminus K$ of the Cantor subset $K\subset [0,1]$ is a connected  Stein dense open subset  of $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ whose complement  $K$ is certainly not analytic. By the way this is a great question because of its divine naïveté and (I think) diabolical difficulty...